# How to change the custom controller url to fancy url in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, url-rewrite, seo

I created a page using conroller with the URL - "mani.magento.com/demo/action/index"
but in the live site that page URL looks like this "mani.magento.com/our-service/hospital-meals/zipcode-details"
How can i match my custom controller URL with live site. How to use (-) symbols in the url.
Thanks..

Comment: You have to implement Custom route https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/routing.html#custom-routers

Comment: Hi @AmitBera thanks for your response. could you pls explain in detail

Answer (score 1):

First you neeed to define a router in your `etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="ingredients_route" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Controller\Router</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">22</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Then define the controller with your own custom logic

```
class Router implements RouterInterface
{
    protected $actionFactory;
    protected $_response;

    public function __construct(
        ActionFactory $actionFactory,
        ResponseInterface $response
    ) {
        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
        $this->_response = $response;
    }

    public function match(RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $pathParts = explode('/', trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/'));

         //Implement your custom logic there by updating the request object

        return $this->actionFactory->create(
            'Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward',
            ['request' => $request]
        );
    }
}
```